# How to make label text(number) change by clicking checkbox?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, checkbox, label, operation

[image]

Teacher gave us an assignment. Checkboxes are lessons that students may choose and labels under them are the free spots left. Basically everytime a lesson(checkbox) selected the number connected to it at label should lessen minus 1. if person unchecks it, number should return to basic.

Sorry for my English, i hope it's understandable.

Comment: Start with making an `OnChange`, or `OnClick` event for the `CheckBox`....

Comment: you'll need to share more info and much more specific when asking questions. 

for example, which technology are you trying to use? Winforms? HTML? WPF?

Comment: Are we to assume that the upper label corresponds to the upper checkbox in each column? Do the radio buttons have any effect here? It would be helpful to see what you have so far. For example, where are the initial numbers coming from, and how are they stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to subscribe to the `CheckedChanged` event for each checkbox. And use [Convert.ToInt32 Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=netcore-3.1) to get the value in labels. Then judge the checkbox selected via `swicth statement`.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    checkBox1.CheckedChanged += checkBox_CheckedChanged;
    checkBox2.CheckedChanged += checkBox_CheckedChanged;
    checkBox3.CheckedChanged += checkBox_CheckedChanged;
}

private void checkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (((CheckBox)sender).Checked)
    {
        switch (((CheckBox)sender).Name)
        {
            case "checkBox1":
                labelofcb1.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(labelofcb1.Text) + 1).ToString();
                break;
            case "checkBox2":
                labelofcb2.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(labelofcb2.Text) + 1).ToString();
                break;
            case "checkBox3":
                labelofcb3.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(labelofcb3.Text) + 1).ToString();
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        switch (((CheckBox)sender).Name)
        {
            case "checkBox1":
                labelofcb1.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(labelofcb1.Text) - 1).ToString();
                break;
            case "checkBox2":
                labelofcb2.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(labelofcb2.Text) - 1).ToString();
                break;
            case "checkBox3":
                labelofcb3.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(labelofcb3.Text) - 1).ToString();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's an example where I picked the `checkedchanged` property of each of the `checkboxs` and this is the function in each of them. you can change the initial value or the changed value as you want by changing the `0` or the `++` or the `--`. You just add the two if conditions from each function to your function and change the name in them to reflect the name of your label.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int counter=0;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            label1.Text = counter.ToString();
        }

        private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkBox1.Checked)
            {
                counter++;
                label1.Text = counter.ToString();
            }
            if (!checkBox1.Checked)
            {
                counter--;
                label1.Text = counter.ToString();
            }
        }

        private void checkBox3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkBox3.Checked)
            {
                counter++;
                label1.Text = counter.ToString();
            }
            if (!checkBox3.Checked)
            {
                counter--;
                label1.Text = counter.ToString();
            }
        }

        private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkBox2.Checked)
            {
                counter++;
                label1.Text = counter.ToString();
            }
            if (!checkBox2.Checked)
            {
                counter--;
                label1.Text = counter.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```